# Is it possible to reach the Claptrap above Marcus's store in Fyrestone?

Tags: borderlands

I have been playing the first Borderlands game for quite some time now, and for the most part I have found it incredibly enjoyable. The gameplay of Roland, Lilith, Mordecai, & Brick stays varied enough to encourage playing as all four characters, and the 4 DLC packs (The Zombie Island of Dr. Ned, Claptrap's New Robot Revolution, The Secret Armory of General Knoxx, & Mad Moxxi's Underdome Riot) add hours of additional fun.

However, while in the Firestone area at the beginning of the game, I noticed something rather odd: a bright, green Claptrap standing on a cliff behind Marcus's store. I have managed to get on top of the store, but have yet been able to reach the little robot. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a hidden easter egg put in for a laugh by the developers. (Note: I do not know if it matters, but my copy of Borderlands is a PS3 Game of the Year Edition)

Answer (score 6):

There is no point in getting to this Claptrap. He doesn't give you anything or talk or provide any type of achievement.

[There is a guy that made a video that shows you how to get to this Claptrap.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjw7x5kbCDM)